# How to toggle-off blank space at the bottom of editor in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem when scrolling to the last line of code because there is a huge space at the bottom of page. Does anyone know how to toggle-off?

I googled and found that The Visual Studio Team will not fix this(https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/3400674-allow-users-to-toggle-off-blank-space-at-the-botto). 
Any workaround?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In settings, set `"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false`

Comment: Thank you. I could not get used to this unnecessary space. It looks like the file is empty…

Comment: "vs code virtual space at bottom".
"visual studio code virtual space at bottom".
I hope google help those who are still struggling with "vs code virtual space".

Comment: how is this space helpful?

Comment: Thank you, this is still the solution in October '21